# Keep footer down with some pages, push it further down on others

Tags: css

I have a website (it's actually an assignment for my course) that has the footer fixed to the bottom of the page with:

```
position: absolute;

bottom: 0;
```

But there is one page in the site that has content that spreads below the bottom of the screen and the footer stays at the bottom of the screen rather than sitting below the content.
So, I need my footer to stay at the bottom of the screen when the content fits onto one screen, and to sit below the content when there's more than will fit onto the screen.
I've already tried all of this:

```
clear: both - on wrapper and content (already on footer)

position: relative, static, fixed

min-height - didn't change anything

height: 100%

overflow: hidden

vertical-align: all values plus a length
```

I also tried using a separate id for the footer only on that page.
But I can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Comment: That looks like it would work but alas, no good. Sometimes things fix themselves when I shut down. Somehow when I come home and start up again it just works how I want. I'll see if that happens this time but obviously, that's wishful thinking.

Comment: Nevermind. One of my teachers suggested I just make the text smaller on the one page that was bothering me, so that should have fixed it.